# dict synonym for parameter in Singleton pattern. Assignment to reserved built-in symbol warning

Tags: python, design-patterns, singleton

In Python a way to implement the Singleton pattern is with metaclasses.

```
class Singleton(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        super(Singleton, cls).__init__(name, bases, dict)
        cls.INSTANCE = None

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls.INSTANCE is None:
            cls.INSTANCE = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls.INSTANCE
```

But in Eclipse with PyDev dict parameter raises a warning: `Assignment to reserved built-in symbol: dict`.

Also PEP 8 says:

> If a function argument's name clashes with a reserved keyword, it is
>   generally better to append a single trailing underscore rather than
>   use an abbreviation or spelling corruption. Thus class_ is better than
>   clss. (Perhaps better is to avoid such clashes by using a synonym.)

I found on the web different names assigned to the parameter instead of dict, such as dictionary, classdict and attrs.

And a approach with *args and **kwargs:

```
class Singleton(type):
    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Singleton, cls).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        cls.INSTANCE = None

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls.INSTANCE is None:
            cls.INSTANCE = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls.INSTANCE
```

I think this last snippet is the best because is safe if type init method changes his signature.

**The questions:**

1. What name do you assign to the parameter instead of dict?
2. What do you think about this last snippet?
3. What do you think is the best option? Change parameter name or use *args and **kwargs?

Comment: Implementing Singleton like this is an anti-pattern. Using a class method is explicit and readable. Oh, and it's not really a singleton: http://ideone.com/E52yj6.

Comment: @lqc You are misunderstand the Singleton pattern. In this [snippet](http://ideone.com/s8BiMe) you could see the classes A and B are Singletons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `dict` is a built-in type, you can use `namespace` or `attributes` or whatever instead. It doesn't really matter here, it is just a local variable name.

   There is no requirement for it to be named anything specific as it is a positional parameter. The [datamodel documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object) uses `namespace`.
2. Using `*args` and `**kwargs` is more than fine there. In fact, the `__init__()` of a metaclass can be passed additional keyword arguments, so it is good practice to pass those on to the super `__init__` method.
3. I'd use `*args` and `**kwargs` when I don't care about the parameters. That way you future-proof the method.

Note that in Python 3, you no longer need to give `super()` any arguments:

```
class Singleton(type):
    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        cls.INSTANCE = None

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls.INSTANCE is None:
            cls.INSTANCE = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls.INSTANCE
```